# How to get different table columns using the same Select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Hi have a table with 9 columns having the same datatype (all are percentage values). I'm trying to create one Select statement in a PL\SQL function to return tuple of 3, depending on an external parameter value.

Syntactically, something like this:

```
WITH tmp
     AS (SELECT '1' col1,
                '2' col2,
                '3' col3,
                '4' col4,
                '5' col5,
                '6' col6,
                '7' col7,
                '8' col8,
                '9' col9
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '10' col1,
                '20' col2,
                '30' col3,
                '40' col4,
                '50' col5,
                '60' col6,
                '70' col7,
                '80' col8,
                '90' col9
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '100' col1,
                '200' col2,
                '300' col3,
                '400' col4,
                '500' col5,
                '600' col6,
                '700' col7,
                '800' col8,
                '900' col9
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE
           WHEN externaparameter = 1 THEN (col1, col2, col3)
           WHEN externaparameter = 2 THEN (col4, col5, col6)
           WHEN externaparameter = 3 THEN (col7, col8, col9)
       END
  INTO var1, var2, var3
  FROM tmp;
```

I have two solutions for this:

Implement CASE statements for each column. But it will create a large select statement and maybe confusing.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN externaparameter = 1 THEN col1
           WHEN externaparameter = 2 THEN col4
           WHEN externaparameter = 3 THEN col7
       END,
       CASE
           WHEN externaparameter = 1 THEN col2
           WHEN externaparameter = 2 THEN col5
           WHEN externaparameter = 3 THEN col8
       END,
       CASE
           WHEN externaparameter = 1 THEN col3
           WHEN externaparameter = 2 THEN col6
           WHEN externaparameter = 3 THEN col9
       END
  INTO var1, var2, var3
  FROM tmp;
```

Or, implement three select statement, with a union. But my original query have a couple of WHERE conditions and for that case I need to repeat them.

```
SELECT a, b, c
  INTO var1, var2, var3
  FROM (SELECT col1 a, col2 b, col3 c
          FROM tmp
         WHERE externalparameter = 1
        UNION
        SELECT col4 a, col5 b, col6 c
          FROM tmp
         WHERE externalparameter = 2
        UNION
        SELECT col7 a, col8 b, col9 c
          FROM tmp
         WHERE externalparameter = 3)
```

Did I have a more clean Select statement for this problem? And what are the advantages and drawbacks for each solutions?

Comment: This approach sound a little hokey.  Instead, I would consider a single procedure that would encapsulate a single SQL that returns all the rows, then wrap this with procedure or procecures to interpret the parm and return the appropriate rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't selectively run one of three separate queries at run time based on `externalparameter` then option one using the `case` expressions is the cleaner solution.

Problems with the `union` solution:

1. Check the query plan generated to be sure, but I imagine that it will execute three separate select statements though they are mutually exclusive. (Unless 12c is much smarter than query optimizes I've word with to date.) This is because the plan might be reused so the plan has to include all three selects to have the correct one in all cases.
2. The `union` version includes an implicit distinct which either adds work if things are already distinct in the first version. Or changes the results versus the first version.

Dynamic SQL is sometimes used in cases like this, but I think three static statements run selectively would be better than building a dynamic SQL string.